# Firebase php-jwt Token Refresh

Tags: refresh, token, jwt

I'm using the php-jwt package for my Restful API to authneticate users.

I am successfully authenticating Users and returning a token. However it seems that there is not a standard method to issue a refresh token. Although I understand the principle and the flow I'm not sure if there is a standard for the issuing of the refresh token?

If I unerstand correctly the flow is as follows:

- App requests access
- API checks for a valid User and issues a token which is to include a refresh token
- refresh token is sent along with a request to renew, it is verified and if valid another token is issued?

But my question is how to issue the initial refesh token. Is this simply encoded in the token itself along with other data that I return such as username and email for example?

Thanks in advance. A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently doing a bit of research of my own on JWTs. I believe you can give the client 2 tokens after auth: an access token and a refresh token. The refresh token can also be a JWT itself. What goes in it is up to you but I think what's important is that it is a valid/not expired token when used. If you can successfully validate it, then you can issue a new access token.